# Catalan and Basque strings in Android not being used

Tags: android

I localized my Android-App in many languages. Unfortunately Catalan and Basque are not working. Whenever I change the device language to one of them, the default strings are shown.

I tried both the regional (`ca-rES, eu-rES`) and the generic (`ca, eu`) version of the strings (`values-ca/strings.xml` or `values-ca-rES/strings.xml`). The system language changes to catalan/basque, but my app stays in english.

Has anyone experienced the same? Any idea?
This is not a duplicate ... the linked question concerns the language on the device, not the strings!

Comment: So, it _is_ working for most other languages? Also - maybe you should add some info to the question. Like the API levels targetted, and the versions of the devices/emulators on which you've tried this. It _might_ just be relevant.

Comment: Yes, it is working in english, german, spanish, arabic ... just not for these two.

Comment: The answer in the dupe targets suggest that the system may not contain the resources for Catalan and Basque. If you do have these resources on your device, it is indeed not a duplicate. Do you have other apps on the device that _are_ able to use Catalan and Basque?

Comment: I found the problem: There is the possibility to change the language inside the app. This changes the short-iso-languagecode (ca, eu etc.) which messed up the configuration of the language. So be careful, when you play with the Locales.

Comment: That sounds different from the answers on the duplicate. Voting to reopen; so that, if this question gets reopened, you can post this as a self-answer. It may help others with the same issue in the future.